# javascript input text using .value is not working

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, events, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to fill out a user form using javascript, however when I use .value to change the element to the customer's name it doesn't work properly. The value change, however once I save the form, the value changed back to its original value. This is the piece of HTML where I'm targeting the customer's name

```
<span class="next-input next-medium"><input placeholder="Name" height="100%" autocomplete="off" value="insert-customer-name" data-spm-anchor-id="a2g0o.placeorder.0.i5.f94f29fdF6dfJe"></span>
```

What I wrote is:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector('.next-input.next-medium input');
inputElement.value = 'Customer Name';
```

I even tried with

```
const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window });
inputElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

// Set the value of the input element to 'Customer Name'
inputElement.value = 'Customer Name';
```

However all the time, the value change to "Customer Name" and then as soon as I manually click on the input or save the form it changed back to 'insert-customer-name' which was the original value.

I would have used puppeteer, but I'm trying to build a chrome extension so I have to stick with javascript since puppeteer is not supported.

Could you please help me to solve it? thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does you use <form> tag? If yes, then after submitting your page is reloaded and your data is deleted.

Comment: yes, it's indeed inside a <form> tag, any solution in this case?

Comment: why not setting the value inside a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { //your code here });`

Comment: It's generally up to the web site that processes the form to show the latest value when redisplaying it. That's not something you need to do in your code.

Comment: just to provide more context, the page where I need to fill out the name is the Aliexpress checkout page

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Answer (score 0):

As you use form tag then when you submit your form, browser automatically reloads your page (and imitate sending to the server ), so your data loses. One of the solution is add this function

Just write at the top of your JS file, where you are changing value this code:

```
const element = document.querySelector('form');
element.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  // actual logic, e.g. validate the form
  console.log('Form submission cancelled.');
});
```

You can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, just to provide more context, the page where I need to fill out the name is the Aliexpress checkout page

Comment: @Lord I made it easier for you and edited it a bit, just put the code above in your JS file. If you have any other forms, then give some unique identifier when picking element with querySelector (class or id). P.S I shared the resource for your in the answer, where you can find another solution for your example.

Comment: still not working